# Wrong computations for struct and time_t

Tags: c++, c, time, struct

Hi I am implementing an algorithm for capturing market data and storing it in an array based on the timings. I am going wrong somehwere and not able to figure out where. This function runs on each market data tick. the idea is to calculate OHLC values at each time interval given by `iCandleTime`

```
//Fucntion to print Market Data Parameters
struct tm * timeinfo;
struct tm sStartTime = {00, 16, 15,15,10,116};
struct tm sEndTime = {00, 16, 16,15,10,116};
struct tm sCandleStartTime = {00, 16, 15,15,10,116};
time_t startTime;
time_t endTime;
time_t candleStartTime;
time_t curTime;
int iCandleTime = 120;
int iTimeInterval = 0;
int iNoCandles = 0;
int iCandleNumber = 0;
static float dNormalOpen = 0, dNormalClose = 0;
static float ohlc[375][4];
int openFlag = 0;
void PrintMarketData(void **args,nsString sPfName)
{
    char sMsg[200];
    nsString sFunctionName = "PrintMarketData";
    nsString sToken;
    sToken = GetPfUserParamValue(sPfName,"CashToken");
    double dLtp=GetDoubleValue(GetParam(sToken, 6));

    curTime = time (NULL);
    //timeinfo = localtime (&curTime);
    startTime = mktime(&sStartTime);
    endTime = mktime(&sEndTime);
    candleStartTime = mktime(&sCandleStartTime);
    iTimeInterval = difftime(endTime, startTime);
    iNoCandles = iTimeInterval / iCandleTime;

    if((difftime(curTime,startTime) >=0) && (difftime(curTime,endTime) < 0) && iCandleNumber<iNoCandles)
    {   
        if((difftime(curTime,candleStartTime) >= 0) && (openFlag == 0)) 
        {
            dNormalOpen = dLtp;
            ohlc[iCandleNumber][0] = dNormalOpen;
            openFlag = 1; //Open is populated in the OHLC Candle
            printf("ST:%s",ctime(&candleStartTime));
            printf(">>> Open:%f CurTime:%s > ST:%s",dNormalOpen,ctime(&curTime),ctime(&candleStartTime));
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Not in open interval...already set");
        }
        if(difftime(curTime,(candleStartTime+iCandleTime)) < 0)
        {
            time_t temp = candleStartTime+iCandleTime;
            dNormalClose = dLtp;
            ohlc[iCandleNumber][3] = dNormalClose;
            printf("### Close:%f CurTime:%s < ET:%s",dNormalClose,ctime(&curTime),ctime(&temp));//incorrect print
        }
        else
        {
            //Log("Not in close interval...already set");
        }
        if((difftime(curTime,(candleStartTime+iCandleTime)) >0) && (openFlag == 1))
        {
            time_t temp = candleStartTime+iCandleTime;
            printf("Temp Time %s",ctime(&candleStartTime)); //correct print
            printf("$$$ Candle No:%d, Open:%f Close:%f Open Time:%s Close Time:%s",iCandleNumber,dNormalOpen,dNormalClose,ctime(&candleStartTime),ctime(&temp)); //incorrect print
            openFlag = 0; //Reset flag for next candle
            iCandleNumber = iCandleNumber + 1; //Increment candle number
            candleStartTime = candleStartTime + iCandleTime;
            printf("Incremented Time %s",ctime(&temp));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Outside Starttime & Endtime ");
        snprintf(sMsg, 200,"Outside Starttime & Endtime ");
        WriteLog(args,sInfo,sFunctionName,sPfName,sMsg);
    }
}
```

The time which I am printing at two places is right at one place and wrong at the other one. Also the looping is going wrong. Am I making any mistake in the time struct and time_t thing Please help
Thnaks in advance

Comment: What is `nsString`?

Comment: "_I am going wrong somehwere_" sure is a cryptic description of your problem. I suggest you "search somewhere" to find the problem. Alternatively, use a debugger or use a debug log file to get a better understanding of what is going on in your algorithm.

Comment: Read the [documentation for `ctime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/ctime), in particular the second sentence in the section about the return value. (The bit that says "POSIX marks this function obsolete and recommends `std::strftime` instead" is also relevant.)

Answer (score 2):

In your calls to ctime, such as in:

```
printf("$$$ Candle No:%d, Open:%f Close:%f Open Time:%s Close Time:%s",
    iCandleNumber,dNormalOpen,dNormalClose,
    ctime(&candleStartTime),ctime(&temp)); //incorrect print
```

you call `ctime` twice. However, the documentation of `ctime` says: "*A call to ctime modifies the **single statically allocated buffer***" so you just overwrote the result of one call to `ctime` with the result of another call to `ctime`.

Call them first and copy the result to your own buffers.